# SQL: How to convert column value into sql operator?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code, on the last part where i typed (+ opr +) gives an error.
Is it possible to convert the opr data value to make it work as > or <?

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  x INTEGER NOT NULL,
  opr varcharacter NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO students VALUES ('Ryan', 15,'<');
INSERT INTO students VALUES ('Joanna', 15,'>');

SELECT * FROM students WHERE x + opr + 4;
```

Comment: @JonathanWillcock can you send me an example

Comment: If there are only the two possibilities, then `where (X<4 and opr ='<') or (X>4 and opr='>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use case inside your where clause

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE
CASE  opr
when '>' then x>4
when '<' then x<4
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic SQL

```
CREATE TABLE students (id INTEGER,name varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,x INTEGER,opr varchar(1));
INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 15,'<');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 15,'>');
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateStudents (_id INTEGER, y INTEGER)
BEGIN
    select @query := CONCAT('SELECT * from students where ',x,' ',opr,' ',y,';')
    from students 
    where id = _id;
    PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @query;
    EXECUTE prepared_statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Call the procedure**

`CALL CalculateStudents(1,4);` not return anything;

`CALL CalculateStudents(2,4);` returns all;

Comment: Can you rewrite the code on this website and copy the code for me https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql

because it's giving me some errors

Error: near line 4: near "DELIMITER": syntax error
Error: near line 10: near "PREPARE": syntax error
Error: near line 11: near "EXECUTE": syntax error
Error: near line 12: near "DEALLOCATE": syntax error
Error: near line 13: near "END$$": syntax error

Comment: Hi @NassimHamza, I used the following compiler online to do this code [paiza](https://paiza.io/projects/VODVSF-JAyDD3JxF0sOz5w?language=mysql) .. You can try to perform the code in your db